# Using GroupWork feature in SP2013

Tags: 2013, feature

The GroupWork feature for calendars was deprecated and hidden going from 2010 to 2013. I need to get this feature working on a 2013 site.

I am using powershell to accomplish this. I have found that I can get the "GroupWork" feature and activate it, doing so creates the appropriate lists and content types. However calendars are not making use of this functionality.

I added Reservations content type to a calendar and when trying to create a reservation item, the Resources list property is empty, despite having added Resources and Resource groups.

I am now looking at the properties of the calendar list and see "EnableResourceSelector". Enabling this did not seem to help with anything. Is there something missing that I need to set to have it consume the resource information properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested some more and found a solution,

1) Either unhide the "GroupWork" feature or activate it through the object model, ie powershell. Doing so will provision the content types and lists required for group work calendars.

2) Ensure the "Reservations" content type is included in your calendar

3) In PowerShell: $yourCalendarList.EnableResourceSelector = $true; $yourCalendarList.Update()

4) HERE IS THE FUN PART! Go into your calendar -> list settings -> List name, description and navigation. Simply open this page up and click Save. This will trigger off whatever needs to be triggered off for the calendar to utilize the Resources list correctly.

Tested in SP2013.